# Main layout doesn't catch onTouchListener

Tags: android

I have implemented for my layout onTouchListener like

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            gdt.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

where I call SimpleOnGestureListener onFling. Problem is that I have inside layout other widgets and I cannot catch with this when you swipe over that widgets. I am trying to implement swipe changing but this main layout doesn't catch when I swipe over big nested widget inside(multiselect list). What to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, but if you're trying to implement horizontal swipe on a view I would recommend using a ViewPager: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html